# How can I get my https:// URL to work both with and without the "www"?

Tags: ssl, virtualhost, https

I thought I had ssl set up correctly, but I discovered a problem.

This part is OK: `ssldomain.com` goes to `https://ssldomain.com`.

But this isn't working: `www.ssldomain.com` is going to `http://anotherdomain.com`, which happens to be the first vhost on the machine. In other words, I have a non-SSL vhost running on that server, and `www.ssldomain.com` is bouncing to that one.

I used [this utiltiy](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) and verified that my Commodo "PositiveSSL" certificate covers the domain both with and without the "www".

I'm using Apache 2.2.3-65.

Here's my config in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf`...

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.ssldomain.com
    ServerAlias ssldomain.com
    DocumentRoot "/opt/deployed_rails_apps/ssl_site/current/public"

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/www.ssldomain.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/www.ssldomain.com.pem
    SSLCACertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/www.ssldomain.com.ca-bundle
    SSLHonorCipherOrder On
    SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:AES128-GCM-SHA256:RC4:HIGH:!MD5:!aNULL:!EDH
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
    Header add Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000"

    ErrorLog "logs/ssldomain.com-ssl-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/ssldomain.com-ssl-access_log" common
    CustomLog "logs/ssldomain.com-ssl-deflate_log" deflate
    <Directory "/opt/deployed_rails_apps/rock_pebble/current/public">
        Options -MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</Virtualhost>
```

---

```
# apachectl -S
VirtualHost configuration:
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
*:443                  ssldomain.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:230)
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server anotherdomain.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:232)
         port 80 namevhost anotherdomain.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:232)
Syntax OK
```

Comment: What's the output from `apachectl -S`?

Comment: That config looks good - the `ssl.conf` vhost will always get every request to port 443, regardless of what host header is on the request.  Are you accessing `http://www.ssldomain.com`, or `https://www.ssldomain.com`?

Comment: Ah OK, yeah. Entering "ssldomain.com" does what I want -- takes you to "https://ssldomain.com". Entering "www.ssldomain.com" serves up the page that's really at "anotherdomain.com", but the browser address bar contains "http://www.ssldomain.com". The status code is 200.

Comment: Is there some way I can redirect "www.ssldomain.com" to "ssldomain.com"? Maybe at the DNS level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, thanks for the help, everyone. I think I have this figured out. I set up both a non-SSL vhost in httpd.conf and the SSL vhost as described in my question in ssl.conf.

The non-SSL vhost has this...

```
ServerName www.ssldomain.com
ServerAlias ssldomain.com
```

And the SSL vhost has only this...

```
ServerName www.ssldomain.com
```

Within my application code, I'm forcing all traffic to go to the corresponding `https` URL. Now the URL resolves both with and without the "www" and everything is served over SSL.

Answer (score 3):

You can't redirect at the DNS level, but you can easily configure another virtual host on port 80 to handle the redirects.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.ssldomain.com
    ServerAlias ssldomain.com
    # .. logging, anything else you need ..
    Redirect permanent / https://ssldomain.com/
</VirtualHost>
```